# Content-Type delimiter

Tags: http, rest, http-headers, mime-types, content-type

Does anyone know which RFC defines how the HTTP content-type header is to be delimited?  I'm posting requests to a restful service using this header:

> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=mysvcboundary

This format of course is what I see in fiddler, chrome tools etc... and also found the same format here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

The only reference I see to how the content-type tag is to be delimited is here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867

But the 1867 RFC seems to be related to HTML file upload which I assume is different than sending a POST request to restful service.  Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 0):

The "Content-Type" header field is defined by HTTP (RFC 2616). The "multipart/form-data" media type is defined by [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578) (a registry of values is maintained by IANA at http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types).

So yes, it's the same type as used by HTML forms.